# How to use the WinAPI & kerberos keytab to create a login session on a domain joined computer?

Tags: windows, winapi, kerberos, pywin32

My apologies if this is a naive question; I am still in the process of understanding auth with active directory, and the capabilities of the Windows API (formerly win32).

Given:

1. A domain-joined Windows computer (let's say Win10+, or Server 2019+);
2. An application, App, running as a service on that computer under the credentials of a gMSA;
3. A kerberos keytab file for user, `User`, in the active directory

Is it possible for App to use the WinAPI (from C, or Python via pywin32) to create a logon session for `User` *on the same computer* and run an arbitrary given command (powershell script, application, etc) as `User`? If so, how?

If it cannot be done, then is there another way for App to create such a logon session and run a command *without* App having direct access to the password for `User`? e.g. Maybe some extra bit of information, or the gMSA having a certain permission, or via some other sort of credentials proxy or built-in credentials provider, or ... etc.

I understand that active directory does use kerberos as its primary (default? only?) auth. So, conceptually, it seems to me that something like this might be possible.

I appreciate your attention. Thank you.

Comment: Are you _required_ to use a keytab? As far as I know, Windows SSPI always requires the original password to be provided and does not support using raw keys as credentials.

Comment: In this instance, yes. I'm trying to determine whether this is possible using a keytab file.